# If A is not mapping reducible to B then A is not mapping reducible to the complement of B?

Tags: complexity-theory

If A is not mapping reducible to B then A is not mapping reducible to the complement of B?

Is this true?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried proving it or coming up with a counterexample?

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Let $B = A_{\mathsf{TM}}$ and let $A = \overline{B}$. Then $A \not\leq_{\mathrm{m}} B$, since $A$ is not a recognizable language and $B$ is recognizable. But we trivially have that $A \leq_{\mathrm{m}} A$.

Comment: is there any such possibility?

Comment: Let $L$ be a language that is neither recognizable nor co-recognizable and let $L'$ be a decidable language. Then we have $L \not\leq_{\mathrm{m}} L'$ and $L \not\leq_{\mathrm{m}} \overline{L'}$, since $\overline{L'}$ is decidable, whenever $L'$ is.